# Exponent font size change when using overbrace

Tags: math-mode, fontsize, overbrace

Looking at the MWE below, the fontsize of the last exponent got enlarged after applying `\overbrace`. How to get its size back to the original as if the overbrace weren't there? Thank you!

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
    e^{-t/\tau} + e^{-\overbrace{t/\tau}^{\theta}}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\scriptstyle t/\tau`